# Curl PHP - 400 Error The request could not be satisfied

Tags: php, api, rest, php-curl

I try to update dates via curl. I use the put statement. I don't know why but every time a get an 400 
 Error.

```
$data = fopen("test.csv", "c");
$ch = curl_init("https://merchants-connector-importercom/key/test.csv");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
array( "x-api-key: fffff","Content-Type: application/json")); 
     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($content);
$decodedJson = json_decode($content, true);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($decodedJson);
```

When I try this, var_dump generates this output:

> string(903) " 400 ERROR The request could not be satisfied. We can't
> connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There
> might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later,
> or contact the app or website owner. If you provide content to
> customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and
> help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID:
> vvNW1rlJyfMLF0tl8Nu3GMGc5K-deL2Os2hb_RENbOsv-GwtUAureg== " NULL

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Should the domain be a .com domain?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that the csv.file was set as a normal file to the curl request. When you use curl you neet to set up a curlFile

```
 $cfile = new CurlFile($file,  'text/csv');
 $data = array('data-binary' => realpath($cfile->getFilename()));
```